# When the FOB is past full capacity, how are soldiers chosen to be dismissed?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

After all open spaces on each FOB deck are full, newly recruited soldiers begin automatically going into the waiting room. Once the total number of soldiers on the FOB (including those in the waiting room) exceeds a maximum value (I think it's around 700), then any time new soldiers are extracted or the FOB receives volunteers, you get a message saying that soldiers were dismissed due to overcrowding.

How does the game decide who to dismiss? Are the soldiers just turned away when the FOB is full, does it try to choose the soldiers with the lowest stats, or is it just random? Having to go through the waiting room and find my least qualified soldiers one by one and dismissing them is tedious, but I'd rather do that than risk having the game dismiss a highly rated soldier I just fultoned in because I don't know how the system works!

Comment: I haven't gotten to this point of staff capacity yet, but I just wanted to mention that if a team is at full capacity, Mother Base automatically puts the lowest-skilled team members in the waiting room to make room for whoever you just recruited (assuming they're better). It wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that Mother Base does the same for overcrowding.

Comment: @Lucas That's true, so I'd like to think that the least qualified staff are let go first, but that applies to individual categories that the game lets you sort by. There isn't a way to sort by lowest/highest stat (not to mean the game doesn't do that by itself), so I wonder what exactly is happening. It'd be easy to confirm if new solders make it in or not at full capacity though, might have to test that later.

Comment: Do you specifically mean Forward Operating Bases, or are you talking about your overall staff?

Comment: @user2357112 Overall staff, I didn't realize you could have multiple bases when I wrote this.

Comment: @QuestionMarks You do raise an interesting question. For instance, would a soldier with Ds in all categories be released before a soldier with one C, and Es in all other categories? The C+E soldier probably has a lower "average", but his one C rank makes him more valuable in practice.

Comment: @recognizer Assume I have 2 soldiers with all E rankings but one has an A in combat, the other has a B in intel. You could objectively say the soldier with the higher single stat is better, but suppose my intel team is terrible compared to combat. This is getting very specific, but if the game isn't dismissing soldiers to my liking, I'd rather manually manage it!

Comment: @QuestionMarks Yeah, the only person who could answer these questions is someone who's paid very close attention to who gets dismissed, and how they compare to the other lowest ranked soldiers in the waiting room at the time. Hopefully someone's looked at that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, motherbase is automatically keeping the higher level soldiers and dismissing the lower level ones. Also special skills are taken into account. Except when you mark soldiers with "direct contract", then motherbase will leave them alone. So you do not have to micro manage your waiting room.